# javascript Date.toISOString() return difference date value

Tags: javascript, date, toisostring

I'm confusing about the javascript Date.toISOString() function which shown as below example, how come date value of x in ISO format become January?

```
const date = new Date();
const x = (new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() , 1));

console.log(date); \\Tue Feb 04 2020 11:11:12 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)
console.log(x); \\Sat Feb 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)

console.log(date.toISOString()); \\2020-02-04T03:11:12.330Z
console.log(x.toISOString()); \\2020-01-31T16:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to time zone conversion from GMT+08 to UTC. The [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) function converts the date to UTC (as a note you can determine that the date is in the UTC time zone by "Z" at the end of the string).

When converting `Feb 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800` to an ISO string, the date is reduced by 8 hours and hence becomes `Jan 31 2020 16:00:00`.